# CSSJSHTML - What does this code means?

Tags: php, javascript, css, jquery

I've some scripts in magento due to the confliction of the below, it is causing some glitch. I need to dig into the below scripts, so that I can find what is the causing the error. Where can I find the files of below code?

```
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `$this` is an instance of `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head`. You will find the method  `getCssJsHtml` in that class.
This method generates the html for the css and js files added to the `<head>` tag.

In order to add a js file to the head tag you can add this to one of the layout files

```
<page_handle_here>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><file>path/to/js/relative/to/js/folder.js</file></action> 
    </reference> 
</page_handle_here>
```

to add a css file:

```
<page_handle_here>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss"><file>path/to/js/relative/theme/folder.css</file></action> 
    </reference> 
</page_handle_here>
```

Comment: I've added my below code in /app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout  
`<reference name="head">
 
<action method="addJs"><file>js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</file></action></reference>`

Comment: @user2366892. you need to wrap your code in a page handle. If you want that available for all the pages wrap it between `<default>YOUR XML HERE</default>`.